# Get thumbnail from Facebook link

Tags: ios, swift, image, facebook, post

Here is my issue. I want to get thumbnail from link. For instance I have Facebook post link: 
https://www.facebook.com/kupriyofficial/videos/226663305259745/
I use one of the iOS frameworks to get image thumbnail using OGP (open graph protocol) and also try to get thumbnail from testing on Postman. They both give me that thumbnail link but in both cases this image thumbnail link was broken (Bad URL timestamp). And no matter what kind of Facebook posts I've got, the result is always the same. Thumbnail link is always broken or failed. Here is the link to image for instance. What should I do? How to get proper working thumbnail link?

```
<meta property="og:image"
    content="https://scontent.flwo3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t15.5256-10/p200x200/94101939_226665698592839_381635971990421504_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&amp;_nc_sid=ad6a45&amp;_nc_ohc=X78oqo9dcu4AX_SlsHj&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.flwo3-1.fna&amp;_nc_tp=6&amp;oh=6f78bc3cdd7d92af5dc65a42a4cc4250&amp;oe=5EE03A30" />
```

Comment: https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkupriyofficial%2Fvideos%2F226663305259745%2F got me https://scontent-frx5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.5256-10/p200x200/94101939_226665698592839_381635971990421504_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&_nc_sid=ad6a45&_nc_ohc=X78oqo9dcu4AX8uNl2z&_nc_ht=scontent-frx5-1.xx&_nc_tp=6&oh=62b909bb8ed6d5d49de5cec01cdf6adc&oe=5EE03A30 as the image URL, and that is working fine for me right now.

Comment: Postman gave me another url for thumbnail image: What do I do wrong?
https://scontent.flwo3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t15.5256-10/p200x200/94101939_226665698592839_381635971990421504_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&amp;_nc_sid=ad6a45&amp;_nc_ohc=X78oqo9dcu4AX_SlsHj&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.flwo3-1.fna&amp;_nc_tp=6&amp;oh=6f78bc3cdd7d92af5dc65a42a4cc4250&amp;oe=5EE03A30

Comment: Explain what exactly you _did_ with Postman …?

Comment: I've added link https://www.facebook.com/kupriyofficial/videos/226663305259745 and set get-request, it gave me html page when I can find go:image with this failed link.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
I have found the solution: replacing & a m p ; with & in the access link works!